# Using loaders in webpack got error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

What's wrong with my code below? I got error bundling less files, for example

```
ERROR in ./~/less-loader!./resources/assets/js/bundle/components/widget/clock.less
```

Below is my webpack.config.js

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ["react-hot", "babel-loader","babel?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015,presets[]=stage-0"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loaders: ['style-loader','less-loader']
      }
    ]
  }
```

I'm trying to implement hot reloading.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @DanielOrmeño updated my question.

Comment: What version of webpack are you using?

Comment: As the error hints, the LESS file has some problem, should check out that file. Or we may need more detailed error messages in order to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `webpack v1`:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ["babel-loader","babel?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015,presets[]=stage-0"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loaders: ['style-loader','css-loader', 'less-loader']
      }
    ]
  }
```

or if you're using `webpack v2`:

```
module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.js?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: ["babel-loader","babel?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015,presets[]=stage-0"],
          },
          {
            test: /\.less$/,
            use: ['style-loader','css-loader', 'less-loader']
          }
        ]
      }
```

Comment: css loader is needed? for?

Answer (score 0):

As your webpack is reaching the less-loader, I don't see any issue in configuration. Otherwise it prompts issue with webpack configuration.

Now you need to check your file here resources/assets/js/bundle/components/widget/clock.less

It is the place which is having issues.

If not please share complete error, this is just the first line of error.